# Django urls.py setup

Tags: python-3.x, django

I'm  getting a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named admin

```
from django.urls import include, path
from django.contrib import admin   
from django.urls import path   
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', include('admin.site.urls')),
    path('learning_log/', include('learning_logs.urls')),
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use the `include` function for the admin site's urls, you simply need to write `admin.site.urls` there (Reference [Hooking AdminSite instances into your URLconf](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#hooking-adminsite-instances-into-your-urlconf)):

```
from django.urls import include, path
from django.contrib import admin   
from django.urls import path   
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls), # No include here
    path('learning_log/', include('learning_logs.urls')),
]
```